# Eclipse (mingw-w64) compiles but still contains errors that prevent a debug session

Tags: c, eclipse, matlab, cmake, mingw-w64

I am working with Eclipse 4.8 and mingw-w64 5.3. It might be of note that the project is also built using CMake 3.12.

I have no issues building the software from the command line using CMake's "MinGW Makefiles" generator. The build is created and I am able to successfully make it. It runs fine.

I am to a point in my development that a GUI debug session would be helpful. I am building a build directory using CMake's "Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles" generator and all seems to go well. I open Eclipse, build the project with MinGW (successfully with no errors and no warnings). However, there are errors shown throughout the actual C file relating to the inclusion of stdlib.h and mat.h (MATLAB library).

It could also be noteworthy that this problem began in the middle of development (i.e. it was working with this software, but now it isn't).

I have read that this is likely the cause of the indexer not matching the compiler, as the compiler is working fine. However, nothing I try is helping. Anyone had this issue or a similar one before? Please let me know if I can provide additional information.

Thanks for your time.

Edit:

Build log from console tab in Eclipse:

```
10:26:43 **** Build of project Reader-Debug@build_eclipse ****
"C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\mingw32-make.exe" all 
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\src -BC:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\build_eclipse --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\build_eclipse\CMakeFiles C:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\build_eclipse\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/ryan/Documents/GitHub/reader/build_eclipse'
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\adr.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/adr.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/ryan/Documents/GitHub/reader/build_eclipse'
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\src C:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\src C:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\build_eclipse C:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\build_eclipse C:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\build_eclipse\CMakeFiles\adr.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target adr
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/ryan/Documents/GitHub/reader/build_eclipse'
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\adr.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/adr.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/ryan/Documents/GitHub/reader/build_eclipse'
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/adr.dir/main.c.obj
C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe  @CMakeFiles/adr.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g   -o CMakeFiles\adr.dir\main.c.obj   -c C:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\src\main.c
[ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/adr.dir/adr.c.obj
C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe  @CMakeFiles/adr.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g   -o CMakeFiles\adr.dir\adr.c.obj   -c C:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\src\adr.c
[100%] Linking C executable adr.exe
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\adr.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\adr.dir/objects.a
C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\adr.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\adr.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g   -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\adr.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o adr.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libadr.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\adr.dir\linklibs.rsp
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/ryan/Documents/GitHub/reader/build_eclipse'
[100%] Built target adr
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/ryan/Documents/GitHub/reader/build_eclipse'
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\ryan\Documents\GitHub\reader\build_eclipse\CMakeFiles 0

10:26:44 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.66ms)
```

Problems tab in Eclipse:

- Errors

  - Symbol 'mat_file' could not be resolved   main.c  /reader-Debug@build_eclipse/[Source directory]  line 31 Semantic Error
  - Symbol 'mat_file' could not be resolved   main.c  /reader-Debug@build_eclipse/[Source directory]  line 103    Semantic Error
  - Symbol 'mat_file' could not be resolved   main.c  /reader-Debug@build_eclipse/[Source directory]  line 104    Semantic Error
  - Symbol 'mat_file' could not be resolved   main.c  /reader-Debug@build_eclipse/[Source directory]  line 248    Semantic Error
  - Type 'FILE' could not be resolved main.c  /reader-Debug@build_eclipse/[Source directory]  line 14 Semantic Error
- Warnings

  - Statement has no effect 'MATFile *mat_file'   main.c  /reader-Debug@build_eclipse/[Source directory]  line 31 Code Analysis Problem

Comment: Additional information - yes - the errors.

Comment: Added the build log and the problems tab information from Eclipse